# Javascript variable or innerHTML value into param value

Tags: javascript, variables, parameters

I wish to retrieve some innerHTML from one part of the html page, and include it in a param tag later in the page.

I've tried using a global javascript variable, where I collect the innerHTML value and then attempt to access this variable from within the param tag. This fails, I guess, because the html tag does not recognise the javascript variable as it's outside a  element.

Collect the innerHTML. I'm using a loop here as I've recycled some old code. Assuming the innerHTML is "PlaceName" locality should wind up looking like "Select_Location=PlaceName".

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var id = "tr#gv-field-4-8\\.1.gv-field-4-8\\.1";
  var locality = ""
  var tds = document.querySelectorAll(id + ' td');
  for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
      console.log(tds[i].innerHTML);
      locality = 'Select_Location='+toUpperCase(tds[i].innerHTML);
  }
</script>
```

Now, the non functioning bit:

Then, later in the document, there's another script that is setting up an iframe. This is the area where parameters are being called. The script is loaded, it checks what is in tableauPlaceholder / teableauViz and reads the params, and creates the iframe. I need to affect the value 'locality' below. 
I guess, and I'm not sure how, that it might also be possible to embed some javascript where 'locality' is so that the params value is evaluated as that element is read?

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://website.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js'></script>
<div class='tableauPlaceholder' style='width: 1000px; height: 1550px;'>
  <object class='tableauViz' width='1000' height='1550' style='display:none;'>
    <param name='filter' value=locality />
  </object>
</div>
```

Currently the value in  does not represent the innerHTML from the element described in the code mentioned at the start. I've not been able to work out how to retrieve this value.

The resulting value should be "Select_Location=PlaceName"

Comment: make sure, JavaScript is executed only after the DOM is loaded completely.

Comment: The javascript execution isn't the issue here, I think. Getting the value of <param> to be the value of the javascript variable is, and if not the javascript variable, then the innerHTML value of the id noted, is. Every bit of javascript is currently executing as intended. The method of getting the value set is the issue.

Comment: I've also tried calling a js function from the value field with "return doWork();", but that's not a working solution.